# File removed with option removing references and deleted from finder directly now showing the warning XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, file, warnings

How can I remove the warning that is showing in XCode?

Warning:

> file:///Users/harjotsingh/Desktop/CoreDataOBJC/CoreDataOBJC/ViewController.m:
>
> warning: Missing file: /Users/harjotsingh/Desktop/CoreDataOBJC/CoreDataOBJC/ViewController.m is missing from working copy

Actually, I have tried all the methods cleaning the project and deleting the installed app from simulator and also deleting the build from library.

Certainly, there is a way to suppress the warning by hiding it. I don't want to hide the warnings. I want to remove them. Could someone suggest me the good way because I am trying this from months and not getting the solution to remove them.

Edited: I have selected remove references for ViewController.m and then deleted the file from finder and it is then showing me the warning.

[image: Check the image]

Comment: "ViewController.m"  is exists in your project ?

Comment: commit your file on git and make sure your file is selected

Comment: First i have deleted the ViewController.m(Move to Trash) without removing references and now i have inserted the ViewController.m with same file name and warnings still showing up.

Comment: have you moved your project?

Comment: No never did that. Actually, this warning occurs everytime when i try to remove the any file from XCode without removing references.

Comment: are you adding file by drag and drop in your project?

Comment: @RichardG No. As i said I have made new project and then just removed ViewController.m from the xcode project. It is showing me warning since then. Which i have been trying for months. I have tried lots of answers on stackoverflow but none of them is actually working that why, I have posted it.

Comment: Search for ViewController.m at project level....see the search result. If you get any remove it.

Comment: Well, there is no ViewController.m in my project because i have moved it to trash without removing references. (Edit: Tried with search results)

Comment: if you are directly trash it, it automatically remove reference form xcode project.

Comment: Well, now it is not showing any warning if i directly trash it earlier it was, now the main problem is if i trash it directly from the xcode project folder and then delete it from xcode itself, the same warnings occur.

Comment: @RichardG check the edit please.I was confused earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode > Preferences > Source control and uncheck "Enable source control"

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SVN/GIT/.. etc, Commit and Push your code and restart your xcode. Missing file warnings will remove.

Comment: I am not using Git or anything to commit or push. This is just a demo project. I am finding the problem why warning is not getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, click on Project Navigator. Select ViewController.m and from the **File Inspector** present on the right hand side select the **small folder icon**. Now you can select the location of the file in Finder and click choose.
This will create a reference to the file whose reference is being shown as missing.

[image: refer this image to find the button I am talking about.]

Comment: Tried bro not working either. :( warnings still showing up.

Comment: What is the version of your XCode?
I tried to reproduce the problem by:
1. creating new XCode project
2. selecting the file in project navigator in XCode.
3. Pressing delete button from keyboard.
4. Selecting Move to trash option.

But my XCode doesn't show up any error.

Comment: Yeah i did. But @HarjotSinghPanesar I cannot reporduce the problem you are facing, as my XCode doesn't show me any warning.

Comment: Its fine bro. I have made the edit again now. Thanks for your answer and time. I have learned a new thing from you but my problem is with the missing file warning which can be removed by deactivating the Source Control.

Comment: @HarjotSinghPanesar Hey, no problem. It's always a pleasure to help.